rhel 8 subscription-manager-gui not found
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/57669
however trying subscription-manager-gui per the redhat article that says it's for rhel 5..9 and also updated 10/2/2024 @ 9am  results in not found on my rhel-8.10 install from iso.
what's the deal?  is rhsm text only now in rhel 8 and later?  I had a nice gui in rhel-7.

From what I see this tool is not available anymore (at least in RHEL 8 and 9). But you can create quite simple command to subscribe (or check subscription) of the machine. If Simple Content Access is enabled you can check the status of the machine via RH console

Yes, apparently the GUI was dropped with Python 3 in RHEL 8. RHEL 8 and later only have the text interface.
